# Rails 3 - Different Class Behavior in rails console vs rails server

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm referencing a custom class from within a model named Plac

Model is defined in models/plac.rb like this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  def notify_owner

    notifier = BatchNotify.getInstance
  end


end
```

BatchNotify is defined in lib/modules/batch_notify.rb like so:

```
class BatchNotify

  def self.getInstance
    env = Rails.env
    if(env == "test")
      return TestBatchNotify.new
    else

      BatchNotify.new
    end
  end
end
```

I have also added the modules directory to autoload_path:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/modules)
```

The weird thing is that when notify_owner() works great from the rails console.

However, when I start the web server with rails server and try to trigger notify_owner by using the app in the browser, I get the following error:

uninitialized constant Plac::BatchNotify

First, why is the behavior different in  console vs web server?

Second, why does it still not recognize the Batch notify constant?

By the way, I've also tried defining BatchNotify within a module and referencing it as Module::BatchNotify with no luck...

Comment: Never depend on Rails' autoloading features. Always require your dependencies. Add **require 'modules/batch_notify'** in your model.

**rails console production** should have similar issues.

Comment: There is a good answer already. But as an addidional hint..if you write ::BatchNotify instead of BatchNotify rails will search for the constant outside of the model class scope.

Comment: Mattherick I've tried that. I get this error:  uninitialized constant BatchNotify

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to get the BatchNotify class loaded properly.

Add a config/initializers/00_requires.rb file with the following code:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/modules/batch_notify.rb"
```

Or, require models/placebo.rb in the `Model` class:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/modules/batch_notify.rb"
```

A couple of other comments on this code:

1. Rails already uses the term models, so `Model` is not a good class name in Rails.
2. The file naming convention is that the file name should correspond with the model name.  So, the models/placebo.rb should be renamed to models/model.rb to follow convention.
3. BatchNotify is a class so I don't think you should put it a directory name modules.

Comment: Powers  thanks for yours answers. just FYI I was not using model as the name of my model, I just made an incomplete attempt to rename the model before posting. i was renaming the model to protect our code.  modules is just a name of a folder in the real sense of a module, meaning bite-sized pieces of code that can be used independently. not ruby modules. I definitely understand the difference between a module and a class.  The code works ONLY if I declare BatchNotify inside plac.rb. requiring the code does not even work, no matter what I do. Perhaps upgrading to rails 4 might help..?

Comment: @PMoses - upgrading to Rails 4 should have nothing to do with this.  When you require the file, add a puts statement and see if true or false is returned.  Also, try running `puts require "#{Rails.root}/lib/modules/batch_notify.rb"` in Rails console and see what is returned.  My only remaining guesses as to what is going wrong is that you are using the wrong path name or using the directory name modules is somehow messing with Rails.